# How to wrap <object> (or <embed>) in <a> and disable object click event (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to navigate some url by clicking on swf file. I have to hide ancor url

```html
<a id="bottomLink" style="display: block; z-index: 10000" 
onclick="replaceAdLinkTech(this);" href='' target='_blank'>
    <div onclick="replaceAdLinkTechEmbed(this)">
        <object  onmousedown="event.preventDefault(); return false;" 
        onclick="event.preventDefault(); return false;" id="bottomEmbedSWF" 
        style="display: none;" width="728" height="90" 
        data="/Content/Images/Main/tehno-bottom.swf">
        </object>
    </div>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function replaceAdLinkTech(el) {
   el.setAttribute("href", "https://ad.admitad.com/g/95d8174bcc812e836de5e20a1b9cd2/");
    return true;
}
```

When tag `img` inside (instead `object`) all works great, but swf `object` (and `embed`) tags beave themself differently.

How to fire ancor click event properly?

Edited.......

I handle it for chrome, but not for firefox. I add 2 eventlisteners:

```
var bottomAd = document.getElementById("bottomEmbedSWF");
bottomAd.addEventListener(
    'click', stopDefAction, false
);
bottomAd.addEventListener(
    'mousedown', stopDefAction, false
);


function stopDefAction(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var bottomAdbottomAdLink = document.getElementById("bottomLink");
    bottomAdbottomAdLink.click();
    return false;
}
```

I don't know what to do with firefox (it should work accordingly their documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/event/preventDefault)

Comment: I can't  verify it right now, but afaik `object` and `embed` are interactive elements and are as of that not allowed to be inside of an `a`.

Comment: @t.niese, thanks for reply. So... what to do? How to fix?

Comment: I think you would need to use js and set `window.location` when the click happens. But I dont have a pc right here to test anything.